# ruby, override a method that is not inherited from a superclass, but added dynamically by a framework (devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, devise

In a rails application, the first line of a controller class is:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

I need to put a breakpoint inside the method `autheticate_user!`.

I discovered that this is a method that is added to the class. So it's not inherited from the super class, If it were i could do:

```
def authenticate_user!

    super.authenticate_user!

end
```

Since there's no authenticate_user! in the superclass, this gives me:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `authenticate_user!' for #<User:0xbec65c0>)
```

My problem is that i don't know where to stop the execution during authentication, or how to implement a trick in order to intercept such process.

Comment: I've edited the question, make the point more clear a get a quick and very clear answer. Could you please remove the close vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`alias_method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-i-alias_method) should work:

```
alias_method :orig_authenticate_user!, :authenticate_user!
def authenticate_user!
  orig_authenticate_user!
end
```